# boost::filesystem::path for unicode file paths?

Tags: c++, path, boost-filesystem

Is there a way to use boost::filesystem::path with unicode file paths?
In particular I'd like to use it with std::wstring instead of std::string.

I'm working on the windows platform and I need to sometimes process a filepath that has a unicode char in it.

Comment: Note: unicode and wstring is not the same, wstring refer to wide characters (usually 16bits) while unicode refer to the character encoding, which could be 8bit, 16bit or even 32bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp), I see a wpath that's templated with std::wstring.

Comment: Note: wpath has since been deprecated in boost::filesystem3