# How to convert between C++Builder UnicodeString and boost string?

Tags: boost, c++builder, edit, unicode-string

I have an application which searches for a file in part of the filesystem.The user is supposed to enter the name of a file in an edit box and that way I assign its value to `UnicodeString` variable.How can I convert it to `boost::filesystem::path` then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/394564/471164 may help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `w_str()` method of `UnicodeString` to retrieve a `wchar_t *`

```
UnicodeString foo = Edit1->Text;

boost::filesystem::path p(foo.w_str());
```